# Why am I getting a 'cannot read properties of null' error with dot notation in React, and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

using traditional ways of accessing objects with dot notation `{quote.text}` `{quote.author}` i'm receiving a "cannot read properties of null" error

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import "./React.css";


   
function getRandomQuote(quotes) {
    return quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  }
  
  export default function App() {
    const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
    const [quote, setQuote] = useState(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          setQuotes(json);
          setQuote(json[0]);
        });
    }, []);
  
    function getNewQuote() {
      setQuote(getRandomQuote(quotes));
    }

  
    return (
      <main>
        <h1>Project 3: Quote Generator</h1>
        <section>
          <button onClick={getNewQuote}>New Quote</button>
          <h3>
            {quote.text}
          </h3>
          <i>- {quote.author}</i>
        </section>
      </main>
    );
  }
```

When I tried question mark with dot notation {quote?.text} {quote?.author} I got back my intented results. What was causing the error with regular dot notation?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import "./React.css";


   
function getRandomQuote(quotes) {
    return quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  }
  
  export default function App() {
    const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
    const [quote, setQuote] = useState(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
          setQuotes(json);
          setQuote(json[0]);
        });
    }, []);
  
    function getNewQuote() {
      setQuote(getRandomQuote(quotes));
    }

  
    return (
      <main>
        <h1>Project 3: Quote Generator</h1>
        <section>
          <button onClick={getNewQuote}>New Quote</button>
          <h3>
            {quote?.text}
          </h3>
          <i>- {quote?.author}</i>
        </section>
      </main>
    );
  }
```

Comment: That means `quote` is null. You seem to be initializing it as null when you do `useState(null)`.

Comment: You've set `quote` to `null` at the beginning and then you are trying to do `quote.text` which is `null.text`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for having a `?` is that this variable could be `null`.
Since `quote` was null, that's why you were getting this error.

At first, it will be null:

```
const [quote, setQuote] = useState(null);
```

Then when you call `getNewQuote` it won't be null anymore, but at first it will

Answer (score 0):

With `const [quote, setQuote] = useState(null);`, the inital state for `quote` is set to `null`. On the first render (note that the `useEffect` callback is executed after render), you will be trying to access `null.text`; this clearly causes an error.

As you've found, using optional chaining is one way to fix it. Another method would be set the initial state to an empty object (`useState({})`): that way, you can access properties on it and get `undefined` which will result in nothing being rendered in that spot.